# Ternary operator for exceptions? Other alternatives?

Tags: c#, exception, monads, ternary-operator

Assuming we have a given object of type Person and want to store its Name property in to a local variable while avoiding possible exceptions should the object be null, we can do this:

```
string personName = null;

if (person != null)
{
    personName = person.Name;
}
```

However, having to declare the variable outside the scope of the if statement and initialize it to a default value is a bit cumbersome. Instead, we can write it like this using the conditional ternary operator:

```
string personName = person != null ? person.Name : null;
```

This same sort of problem exists when dealing with try-catch statements. Let's say we were trying to find the remote address of a TcpClient. We may do something like this:

```
string remoteAddress = null;

try
{
    remoteAddress = tcpClient.Client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString();
}
catch (SocketException e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);

    return;
}
```

However, as far as I can tell, there is no operator defined for simplifying such a thing, and I suppose for good reason, considering the possible complexity. I wonder though, is there a way to make this sort of thing more concise? Perhaps a solution involving monads would work or maybe this code should be left as it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My personal guess is that such an operator is not available for exceptions because it might encourage bad coding habits. Recall the following best practice guidelines:

1. *Code should not fail silently* and
2. *Exceptions should only be thrown under exceptional circumstances*.

Due to these points, you should not *need* exception handling very often (methods such as `TryParse` help a lot here), except for the top UI level of your application, where you catch and log everything.

In your example, if the TCP connection is broken, the algorithm usually cannot continue anyway, so why not let the socket exception bubble up to the UI layer, where it is caught and a helpful message is displayed to the user ("Connection lost, please check your Internet connection. {Exception Details}"), instead of just returning and silently logging something to the Console, leaving the user wondering why his operation did not complete?

Comment: Things like TCP connections represent a situation where it is often appropriate to throw exceptions which are likely to be caught and handled somewhere, since the code which fails is likely to be within a block or method, and the code to handle the exception outside it.  Using exceptions is far cleaner than "if (!TryReadOneByte(ref commandLength)) break; if (!TryReadNBytes(commandLength, dat)) break;" etc.  A connection failure should abort the current operation, but might very reasonably result in one or more retries (possibly at different addresses) before bubbling up to the caller.

Answer (score 2):

From here: http://devtalk.net/csharp/chained-null-checks-and-the-maybe-monad/

```
public static TResult With<TInput, TResult>(this TInput o, 
                                            Func<TInput, TResult> evaluator)
    where TResult : class where TInput : class
{
    if (o == null) return null;
    return evaluator(o);
}
```

The above method can be attached to any type (because TInput is effectively object). As a parameter, this method takes a function which defines the next value in the chain. If we passed null, we get null back. Let’s rewrite our first example using this method:

```
string postCode = this.With(x => person)
                      .With(x => x.Address)
                      .With(x => x.PostCode);
```

this for an object built "normally" like:

```
var person = new { Address = new { PostCode = "12345" } };
```

but that can have `person` and `Address` `null`. I'll add that in the same page there is a `Result` extension method that returns a default value if the "primary" value is `null`.

In [this](http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2010/10/01/c-5.0-and-beyond---my-wish-list.aspx) page (that was the one that pointed me to the other) it's in a person's wish list at the first place, and he calls it `Null Safe Dereferencing`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a concept of a [Null Object Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern) which I once used successfully. Maybe this is helpful for you, too. To quote:

> In object-oriented computer programming, a Null Object is an object
>   with defined neutral ("null") behavior.

In other words, instead of returning `null` you return a well defined object that acts as the "null object" and thus accessing it does not throw an exception.

Also, [see this Google search](http://www.google.com/search?q=c#%20null%20object%20pattern) for more examples.